# Unexplained Segmentation Fault in simple loop, works with two if statements but not three?

Tags: c, if-statement, segmentation-fault

There is a lot going on so i put some arrows pointing towards the if statements in the add function that are breaking the code. When I test the code with only 2/3 of the if statements that I need to check for false values, it runs perfectly, but if I add in that last if statement I get a seg fault. No idea what the problem could be please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>


typedef struct{

    char name[50];
    double havg;
    double qavg;
    double eavg;

}gradebook_t;


int addStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents, int capacity);
int removeStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents);
void updateStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents, char name[]);
void displayStudents(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents);
void missingStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents);


int main()
{
    gradebook_t classr[5];
    
    int capacity = 5;
    int currentstudents = 0;
    int selection;
    int x = 0;
    char nameUpdate[50];
    
    while(x == 0)
    {
        printf("Choose a selection:\n");
        printf("1. Add a student\n");
        printf("2. Display students\n");
        printf("3. Remove a student\n");
        printf("4. Update a student's info\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n");
        
        scanf("%d",&selection);
        
        if(selection == 1)
        {
            currentstudents += addStudent(classr,currentstudents,capacity);
        }
        else if(selection == 2)
        {
            displayStudents(classr, currentstudents);
        }
        else if(selection == 3)
        {
            currentstudents += removeStudent(classr, currentstudents);
        }
        else if(selection == 4)
        {
            printf("What is the name of the student you would like to update?\n");
            scanf("%s",nameUpdate);
            
            updateStudent(classr,currentstudents,nameUpdate);
        }
        else if(selection == 0)
        {
            x += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not a selection, try again...\n");
            printf("currentstudents = %d",currentstudents);
        }
    }
    


    return 0;
}


int addStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents, int capacity)
{
    if(currentstudents != capacity)
    {
        printf("Enter a student name:");
        scanf("%s", classr[currentstudents].name);
        
        printf("Enter a homework average:");
        scanf("%lf", &classr[currentstudents].havg);
   
    if(classr[currentstudents].havg < 0 || classr[currentstudents].havg > 100)     // <----------
    {
        classr[currentstudents].havg = 0;
    }

        printf("Enter a quiz average:");
        scanf("%lf", &classr[currentstudents].qavg);
   
    if(classr[currentstudents].qavg < 0 || classr[currentstudents].qavg > 100)     // <---------
    {
        classr[currentstudents].qavg = 0;
    }

        printf("Enter an exam average:");
        scanf("%lf", &classr[currentstudents].eavg);
   
    if(classr[currentstudents].eavg < 0 || classr[currentstudents].eavg > 100)     // <-------
    {
        classr[currentstudents].eavg = 0;
    }
    
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The class is full...\n");
    }
 
}


void displayStudents(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < currentstudents; index++)
    {
        printf("Student %d Name : %s\n",index+1, classr[index].name);
        printf("Student %d HW AVG : %.2lf\n",index+1, classr[index].havg);
        printf("Student %d QUIZ AVG : %.2lf\n",index+1, classr[index].qavg);
        printf("Student %d EXAM AVG : %.2lf\n\n",index+1, classr[index].eavg);
    }
}

int removeStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents)
{
    char find1[20];
    int x = 0;

    printf("Enter a student name:");
    scanf("%s",find1);
    
    for(int index = 0; index < currentstudents; index++)
    {
        if(strcmp(find1,classr[index].name) == 0)
        {
            classr[index] = classr[currentstudents-1];
            x = -1;
        }
    
    }
    
    
    return x;
}

void updateStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents, char name[])
{
    double havg2;
    double qavg2;
    double eavg2;

    for(int index = 0; index < currentstudents; index++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name,classr[index].name) == 0)
        {
            printf("Please update the following:\n");
            
            printf("HW AVG:\n");
            scanf("%lf",&havg2);
            classr[index].havg = havg2;
            
            printf("QUIZ AVG:\n");
            scanf("%lf",&qavg2);
            classr[index].qavg = qavg2;
            
            printf("EXAM AVG:\n");
            scanf("%lf",&eavg2);
            classr[index].eavg = eavg2;
            
        }
    
    }
}

void missingStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents)
{

    int x = 0;
    
    printf("Students with missing info:\n");
    
    for(int index = 0; index < currentstudents; index++)
    {
        if(classr[index].havg == 0)
        {
            x += 1;
        }
        if(classr[index].qavg == 0)
        {
            x += 1;
        }
        if(classr[index].eavg == 0)
        {
            x += 1;
        }
        
        if(x>0)
        {
            printf("%s",classr[index].name);
        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note, use a `switch` for `selection`.

Comment: Which function is calling the seg fault?  You should do more debugging, rather than ask us to do it for you.

Comment: It's not even debugging – please read the **compiler warnings**: function `addStudent()` must return a value, used by `currentstudents += addStudent(...);`

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

1. In `addStudent`, you never do `return` with a value(as would be flagged by the compiler with `-Wall`).
2. As such, `main` could see a random/nonsensical value for `currentstudents`, causing UB (undefined behavior), which, in this case, caused a segfault.
3. So, you need to do something similar to what you do in `removeStudent` with `x`
4. But, `removeStudent` is incorrect. It doesn't work in the general case. (e.g.) You have 4 students in the list and want to remove the second one.
5. It's easier/better to have `addStudent/removeStudent` return the *updated* `currentstudents` value rather than an increment/decrement.

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes.

To aid in debugging, I added `echo_scanf` to make the output easier to read if the input was redirected from a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#if 1
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#endif

typedef struct {
    char name[50];
    double havg;
    double qavg;
    double eavg;
} gradebook_t;

int addStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents, int capacity);
int removeStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents);
void updateStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents, char name[]);
void displayStudents(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents);
void missingStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents);

// NOTE: this is a debugging trick where the input is redirected from a file
int echo_scanf(const char *fmt,void *ptr);
#define scanf echo_scanf

int
main(void)
{
    gradebook_t classr[5];

    int capacity = 5;
    int currentstudents = 0;
    int selection;
    int x = 0;
    char nameUpdate[50];

    while (x == 0) {
        printf("Choose a selection:\n");
        printf("1. Add a student\n");
        printf("2. Display students\n");
        printf("3. Remove a student\n");
        printf("4. Update a student's info\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n");

// NOTE/BUG: should check for error/EOF
#if 0
        scanf("%d", &selection);
#else
        if (scanf("%d", &selection) <= 0)
            break;
#endif

        if (selection == 1) {
// NOTE/FIX: changed meaning of return value
#if 0
            currentstudents += addStudent(classr, currentstudents, capacity);
#else
            currentstudents = addStudent(classr, currentstudents, capacity);
#endif
        }
        else if (selection == 2) {
            displayStudents(classr, currentstudents);
        }
        else if (selection == 3) {
// NOTE/FIX: changed meaning of return value
#if 0
            currentstudents += removeStudent(classr, currentstudents);
#else
            currentstudents = removeStudent(classr, currentstudents);
#endif
        }
        else if (selection == 4) {
            printf("What is the name of the student you would like to update?\n");
            scanf("%s", nameUpdate);

            updateStudent(classr, currentstudents, nameUpdate);
        }
        else if (selection == 0) {
            x += 1;
        }
        else {
            printf("Not a selection, try again...\n");
            printf("currentstudents = %d", currentstudents);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int
addStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents, int capacity)
{

    if (currentstudents != capacity) {
        printf("Enter a student name:");
        scanf("%s", classr[currentstudents].name);

        printf("Enter a homework average:");
        scanf("%lf", &classr[currentstudents].havg);

        if (classr[currentstudents].havg < 0 || classr[currentstudents].havg > 100) // <----------
        {
            classr[currentstudents].havg = 0;
        }

        printf("Enter a quiz average:");
        scanf("%lf", &classr[currentstudents].qavg);

        if (classr[currentstudents].qavg < 0 || classr[currentstudents].qavg > 100) // <---------
        {
            classr[currentstudents].qavg = 0;
        }

        printf("Enter an exam average:");
        scanf("%lf", &classr[currentstudents].eavg);

        if (classr[currentstudents].eavg < 0 || classr[currentstudents].eavg > 100) // <-------
        {
            classr[currentstudents].eavg = 0;
        }
// NOTE/FIX: increase number of students
#if 1
        ++currentstudents;
#endif
    }
    else {
        printf("The class is full...\n");
    }

// NOTE/FIX: provide a return value
#if 1
    return currentstudents;
#endif
}

void
displayStudents(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < currentstudents; index++) {
        printf("Student %d Name : %s\n", index + 1, classr[index].name);
        printf("Student %d HW AVG : %.2lf\n", index + 1, classr[index].havg);
        printf("Student %d QUIZ AVG : %.2lf\n", index + 1, classr[index].qavg);
        printf("Student %d EXAM AVG : %.2lf\n\n", index + 1, classr[index].eavg);
    }
}

int
removeStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents)
{
// NOTE/BUG: this has to be at least the same size as the field in the struct
#if 0
    char find1[20];
#else
    char find1[50 + 1];
#endif
#if 0
    int x = 0;
#endif

    printf("Enter a student name:");
    scanf("%s", find1);

    for (int index = 0; index < currentstudents; index++) {
        if (strcmp(find1, classr[index].name) == 0) {
// NOTE/BUG: this only removes one student and it can be the wrong one
#if 0
            classr[index] = classr[currentstudents - 1];
#else
            for (int rindex = index + 1;  rindex < currentstudents; ++rindex)
                classr[rindex - 1] = classr[rindex];
            currentstudents -= 1;
#endif
#if 0
            x = -1;
#endif
        }
    }

#if 0
    return x;
#else
    return currentstudents;
#endif
}

void
updateStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents, char name[])
{
    double havg2;
    double qavg2;
    double eavg2;

    for (int index = 0; index < currentstudents; index++) {
        if (strcmp(name, classr[index].name) == 0) {
            printf("Please update the following:\n");

            printf("HW AVG:\n");
            scanf("%lf", &havg2);
            classr[index].havg = havg2;

            printf("QUIZ AVG:\n");
            scanf("%lf", &qavg2);
            classr[index].qavg = qavg2;

            printf("EXAM AVG:\n");
            scanf("%lf", &eavg2);
            classr[index].eavg = eavg2;

        }

    }
}

void
missingStudent(gradebook_t classr[], int currentstudents)
{

    int x = 0;

    printf("Students with missing info:\n");

    for (int index = 0; index < currentstudents; index++) {
        if (classr[index].havg == 0) {
            x += 1;
        }
        if (classr[index].qavg == 0) {
            x += 1;
        }
        if (classr[index].eavg == 0) {
            x += 1;
        }

        if (x > 0) {
            printf("%s", classr[index].name);
        }

    }
}

// scanf wrapper for debug
int
echo_scanf(const char *fmt,void *ptr)
{
    char buf[100];

    // decide if stdin is redirected from file
    static int isa_file = -1;
    if (isa_file < 0) {
        struct termios tio;
        isa_file = (tcgetattr(0,&tio) < 0);
    }

    while (1) {
        if (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin) == NULL)
            exit(0);
        if (strcmp(buf,"\n") != 0)
            break;
    }

    // pretty print if file input (i.e. "echo" the user input as /dev/tty would)
    if (isa_file)
        fputs(buf,stdout);

    int ret = sscanf(buf,fmt,ptr);

    return ret;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is the test input I used:

```
1
Fred
37
23
17

2

1
Mary
62
59
43

2

1
Charles
7
6
3

2

3
Mary

2

0
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
Choose a selection:
1. Add a student
2. Display students
3. Remove a student
4. Update a student's info
0. Exit
1
Enter a student name:Fred
Enter a homework average:37
Enter a quiz average:23
Enter an exam average:17
Choose a selection:
1. Add a student
2. Display students
3. Remove a student
4. Update a student's info
0. Exit
2
Student 1 Name : Fred
Student 1 HW AVG : 37.00
Student 1 QUIZ AVG : 23.00
Student 1 EXAM AVG : 17.00

Choose a selection:
1. Add a student
2. Display students
3. Remove a student
4. Update a student's info
0. Exit
1
Enter a student name:Mary
Enter a homework average:62
Enter a quiz average:59
Enter an exam average:43
Choose a selection:
1. Add a student
2. Display students
3. Remove a student
4. Update a student's info
0. Exit
2
Student 1 Name : Fred
Student 1 HW AVG : 37.00
Student 1 QUIZ AVG : 23.00
Student 1 EXAM AVG : 17.00

Student 2 Name : Mary
Student 2 HW AVG : 62.00
Student 2 QUIZ AVG : 59.00
Student 2 EXAM AVG : 43.00

Choose a selection:
1. Add a student
2. Display students
3. Remove a student
4. Update a student's info
0. Exit
1
Enter a student name:Charles
Enter a homework average:7
Enter a quiz average:6
Enter an exam average:3
Choose a selection:
1. Add a student
2. Display students
3. Remove a student
4. Update a student's info
0. Exit
2
Student 1 Name : Fred
Student 1 HW AVG : 37.00
Student 1 QUIZ AVG : 23.00
Student 1 EXAM AVG : 17.00

Student 2 Name : Mary
Student 2 HW AVG : 62.00
Student 2 QUIZ AVG : 59.00
Student 2 EXAM AVG : 43.00

Student 3 Name : Charles
Student 3 HW AVG : 7.00
Student 3 QUIZ AVG : 6.00
Student 3 EXAM AVG : 3.00

Choose a selection:
1. Add a student
2. Display students
3. Remove a student
4. Update a student's info
0. Exit
3
Enter a student name:Mary
Choose a selection:
1. Add a student
2. Display students
3. Remove a student
4. Update a student's info
0. Exit
2
Student 1 Name : Fred
Student 1 HW AVG : 37.00
Student 1 QUIZ AVG : 23.00
Student 1 EXAM AVG : 17.00

Student 2 Name : Charles
Student 2 HW AVG : 7.00
Student 2 QUIZ AVG : 6.00
Student 2 EXAM AVG : 3.00

Choose a selection:
1. Add a student
2. Display students
3. Remove a student
4. Update a student's info
0. Exit
0
```